# laravel - error with wherehas and relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

categories has a self relationship.

Here's my code for my advanced search:

```
        $allcats = array();
    if(in_array('1',$category) OR in_array('2',$category) OR in_array('3',$category)) {
        foreach($category as $c) {
            foreach(Category::where('parentid',$c)->get()->toArray() as $cat) {
                $allcats[] = $cat['id'];
            }
        }
    } else {
        $allcats = $category;
    }

    $query->whereHas('categories', function($q) use($allcats)
    {
        $q->whereIn('category.id', $allcats);
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is, getting all the childrencategories from the three main cats (works fine, I think). And then, getting all related recipes for EACH categorie in the array, here:

```
        $query->whereHas('categories', function($q) use($allcats)
    {
        $q->whereIn('category.id', $allcats);
    });
```

and this is not working. Somehow I'm always getting 4 results instead of 10 (all)!
What am I doing wrong? `$allcats` looks like this:

```
[
"6",
"7",
"5",
"9",
"12",
"13",
"14",
"17",
"18",
"19",
"20",
"21",
"24",
"25",
"26"
```

]

looks fine for me too.
Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT #1:

```
    <?php

class Recipe extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'recipes';

    public function categories() {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Category','category_recipe');
    }
```

and Category:

```
    <?php

class Category extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'category';

    public function recipes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Recipe');
    }

    public function parent_category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category','parentid');
    }

    public function child_categories() {
        return $this->hasMany('Category','parentid');
    }
```

Comment: Show the model that runs the query. Btw what is that you are trying to get in the 1st piece of code?

Comment: I added the two models. The first piece is getting the GET from the URL.. if category is one of the three maincategories (id 1-3) it get's all the children to those too.

Comment: It seems that you get all that you have in your db. Check the query that is run (with DB::getQueryLog() for example) and compare to the data in your db.